# rotatable animated sprites GLES 1

Tags: opengl-es, rotation, sprite

glDrawTexfOES cannot be rotated and vertex buffer objects have set uv coordinates which i cant change because of non-programmable shaders in GLES 1, how do i make animated rotatable sprites  with spritesheets in GLES 1

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change uv coordinates with texture matrix.

But to rotate sprites - draw them as quads (using two triangles) and apply rotation matrix to vertex positions.

Comment: thanks i know the nomarl rotation matrix but i did not know there actually was a texture matrix :),